# T-SQL query with case statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `phone` table with three columns

```
Person_Name, Phone_Type, Phone_Number
```

In this table, multiple people have three phone numbers with their phone types. For example, John has Phone_Type "P" (Permanent), "PC" (Personal cell), and "F" ("Fax").

What I am trying to pull is show me all the distinct person's phone numbers if a Personal cell is not available then show me Permanent numbers and if the Permanent number is missing then show me the Fax number in one query.

Appreciate your help on this.

I am running out of ideas

Comment: what happens when you have two users with the same name?

Comment: ...or one user with two fax numbers

Comment: Describe structure

Comment: You have got great attention today (too good, to be honest), but the next time you ask a question, start with a [mcve]. Make it easy to assist you!

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the much more fundamental problem that maybe you simplified away (`Person_Name` is not unique enough to describe exactly one person), it is much more efficient to only make a single pass over the table ([the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75513614/61305) does 6 table scans, for example), e.g.

```
SELECT Person_Name, Phone_Number = MAX
  (
    CASE x.Phone_Type WHEN 'PC' THEN x.Phone_Number
                      WHEN 'P'  THEN x.Phone_Number
                      WHEN 'F'  THEN x.Phone_Number END
  )
FROM dbo.phone
CROSS APPLY 
(
  VALUES(Phone_Type, Phone_Number)
) AS x
GROUP BY Person_Name;
```

Working db<>fiddle (with a more correct schema IMHO that doesn't have to treat two John Smiths as the same person) [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Id-m-Fr3). The schema there also prevents any user from having, for example, two fax numbers. The query performs exactly one scan of the table/CIX. The only difference from the above query is that you include the column that uniquely identifies a person, e.g. if the (missing) primary key is `Person_Id`:

```
SELECT Person_Id, Person_Name, Phone_Number = MAX
  (
    CASE x.Phone_Type WHEN 'PC' THEN x.Phone_Number
                      WHEN 'P'  THEN x.Phone_Number
                      WHEN 'F'  THEN x.Phone_Number END
  )
FROM dbo.phone
CROSS APPLY 
(
  VALUES(Phone_Type, Phone_Number)
) AS x
GROUP BY Person_Id, Person_Name;
```

Comment: This still fails if you have more than one user with the same name.

Comment: @Ryan Yes because either the user only has unique users already or they probably have an additional column they haven't told us about. [Did you look at the actual example I posted](https://dbfiddle.uk/Id-m-Fr3)?

Comment: I did. And you have made assumptions based on information that doesn't exist  in the post. Based on what is provided your answer will still fail. "I have a phone table where I have three fields in it." - (Seems pretty concrete)

Comment: "Fail" how? If the user has two different John Smiths in their table and can't tell them apart, they have much bigger problems. Do you have an answer that will "work" without making pretty basic assumptions based on information that doesn't exist in the post? Please post it so it can be equally critiqued. If you are certain that they are in this state, then the question can't be answered at all and should be deleted? I think answers can still be useful _especially_ when the example actually provides constructive guidance on how to improve the schema. YMMV.

Comment: Exactly, the user has bigger problems to address. I wouldn't provide an answer for something that needs clarification, so, yes, the post should most likely be deleted or updated with more information. And if I  really wanted to critique your answer I would have cast a down vote and not bothered to comment at all like so many do on this site.

Comment: @RyanWilson So are you suggesting we should all delete our answers and then ask the user to come back when they've fixed the schema (or can describe it more accurately)? Maybe they have an ill-advised unique constraint on `Person_Name`, in which case the solutions here work too. Or they over-simplified (here are the three columns I'm bothered to tell you about). If we demanded every person posting have a perfect and perfectly-described schema, we'd never answer any questions at all.

Comment: @RyanWilson For all we know, the table represents _people in their house_. Or isn't even about people and phone numbers at all, this was just an easy example to come up with that they could then translate to their real schema that maybe isn't vulnerable to the "two John Smiths" issue. The problems are _notable_ (which many people have already brought up) but, IMHO, completely separate from how to solve the query the user asked to solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Person_Name, 
       COALESCE(
         (SELECT Phone_Number FROM phone WHERE Person_Name = p.Person_Name AND Phone_Type = 'PC'),
         (SELECT Phone_Number FROM phone WHERE Person_Name = p.Person_Name AND Phone_Type = 'P'),
         (SELECT Phone_Number FROM phone WHERE Person_Name = p.Person_Name AND Phone_Type = 'F')
       ) AS Phone_Number
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Person_Name
  FROM phone
) p;
```

The innermost subquery selects all distinct person names from the phone table.
The middle part of the query uses COALESCE to return the first non-null value among the three subqueries.

Comment: what happens when you have two users with the same name? This won't work anymore as John Smith in California is not the same as John Smith in Pennsylvania. The database schema needs to be changed for this to even work in a consistent fashion and then it would need modified for the phone records to store a unique id of each user and you could filter on a distinct identity

Comment: You are right about this +!

Comment: This gets the right answer, but it has to perform [6 table (or CIX) scans](https://dbfiddle.uk/jHo6j9es) to get there, so it won't perform very well at scale.